# Redux not Re-rendering React components even though store is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Hi I'm new to Redux and I'm using React and Redux to try to build a UI where I can drag and drop files (invoices in this case) into a portion of the UI, render them in a list and then be able to launch a popover to edit the metadata associated with each invoice.  Dragging and dropping is all working fine - Redux is re-rendering the view each time a file is dropped and the list is being updated. However, when I try an click the edit button against each invoice the store is being updated but the props in my popover component are not. Indeed, it doesn't look like any re-rendering is happening at all when I attempt to click the edit invoice button

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import AddInvoice from '../containers/AddInvoice'
import CurrentInvoiceList from '../containers/CurrentInvoiceList'
import ControlPopover from '../containers/ControlPopover'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AddInvoice />
    <CurrentInvoiceList />
    <ControlPopover />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

containers/AddInvoice.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addInvoice } from '../actions'

const recipientDataDefaults = {
  name: '',
  surname: '',
  address: '',
  phone: ''
};

const handleDragOver = event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
};

const handleDragEnter = event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
};

const handleDragLeave = event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();    
};

let AddInvoice = ({ dispatch }) =>
  const styles = {'minHeight': '200px', 'background': 'tomato'}
  return (
    <div style={styles}
         onDragEnter={handleDragEnter} 
         onDragLeave={handleDragLeave} 
         onDragOver={handleDragOver} 
         onDrop={event => {
           event.stopPropagation(); 
           event.preventDefault();
           const data  = event.dataTransfer;
           const files = data.files;

           const newInvoiceUploads = Object.keys(files)
             .map(key => files[key])
             .map(file => {
               const invoiceObject = {};
               invoiceObject.files = [file];
               invoiceObject.recipientData = Object.assign({}, recipientDataDefaults);
               return invoiceObject;
             });

           newInvoiceUploads.forEach(invoice => dispatch(addInvoice(invoice)))

    }}>
      Drag an invoice here to upload
    </div>
  )
}
AddInvoice = connect()(AddInvoice)

export default AddInvoice
```

containers/ControlPopover.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { closePopoverWithoutSave } from '../actions'
import Popover from '../components/Popover/Popover'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isActive: !!state.isActive
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  handleCancel: closePopoverWithoutSave
}


const ControlPopover = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Popover)

export default ControlPopover
```

containers/CurrentInvoiceList.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { showInvoiceEditPopover } from '../actions'
import InvoiceList from '../components/InvoiceList/InvoiceList'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    invoices: state.invoices
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleEditInvoice: invoice => {
    dispatch(showInvoiceEditPopover(invoice))
  }
})

const CurrentInvoiceList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(InvoiceList)

export default CurrentInvoiceList
```

actions/index.js

```
let nextInvoiceId = 0
export const addInvoice = invoice => ({
  type: 'ADD_INVOICE',
  id: nextInvoiceId++,
  invoiceData: invoice
})

export const showInvoiceEditPopover = invoice => ({
  type: 'SHOW_POPOVER',
  invoice
})
```

The popover reducer (combined in app but inlined here for brevity) reducers/index.js

```
const popover = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_POPOVER':
      const popoverState = {}
      popoverState.isActive = true
      popoverState.data = action.invoice
      return popoverState

     case 'CLOSE_POPOVER_WITHOUT_SAVING':
       const inactiveState = {}
       inactiveState.isActive = false
       inactiveState.data = {}
       return inactiveState;
     default:
       return state
   }
}

export default popover
```

components/InvoiceList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Invoice from '../Invoice/Invoice'

const InvoiceList = ({ invoices, handleEditInvoice }) => {

return (
  <div>
    {invoices.map(invoice =>
      <Invoice
        key={invoice.id}
        invoice={invoice.invoiceData}
        onClick={event => {
          // here we invoke the action bound by the CurrentInvoiceList
          // container
          event.preventDefault()
          handleEditInvoice(invoice)
        }}
      />
    )}
  </div>
 )
}

InvoiceList.propTypes = {
  invoices: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    invoiceData: PropTypes.object
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
  handleEditInvoice: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default InvoiceList
```

components/Invoice.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import TextInput from '../TextInput/TextInput';
import Button from '../Button/Button';
import './invoice.css'

const Invoice = ({ invoice, onClick }) => {

const fileNames = invoice.files.map((file, index) => {
    return (<div key={index} className="invoice__file-title-legend">
   {file.name}</div>);
  });

return (
    <div className="invoice">
    <form className="invoice__form">
    <TextInput id="invoice__input-amount" placeholder="enter invoice amount" label="Invoice Amount" />
    <TextInput id="invoice__input-target" placeholder="enter payment target" label="Payment Target" />
    <Button value="Add recipient" onClick={onClick} /> // clicking this button updates the store but does NOT re-render. Why?
  </form>

  <div className="invoice__files">{fileNames}</div>
</div>
  )
}

Invoice.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  invoice: PropTypes.object
}

export default Invoice
```

components/Popover/Popover.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import createModifiers      from '../../lib/createModifiers';
import './Popover.css';

const Popover = ({ handleCancel, isActive }) => {
  console.log('rendering popover component') // does not get called when invoice edit button is pressed
  const popoverModifiers = createModifiers('popover', {
    'is-active': isActive
  })

  return (
    <div className={popoverModifiers}>
      <div className="popover__header">
        <button onClick={handleCancel}>x</button>
      </div>
      <div className="popover__content">
       Popover content
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
Popover.propTypes = {
  handleCancel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isActive: PropTypes.bool.isRequired 
}

export default Popover
```

And finally the createModifiers Code for posterity. This code is merely producing some BEM modifier CSS classes based on a state boolean value passed in

```
const createModifiers = (element, modifiers) => {
  const classList = Object.keys(modifiers)
    .filter(key => modifiers[key])
    .map(modifier => `${element}--${modifier}`)
    .concat(element)
    .join(' ')

  return classList
}

export default createModifiers
```

I know this is a large amount of example code so I tried to keep it a brief and focused as possible whilst giving a comprehensive view of the application. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Does mapStateToProps of Control Popover get called ?

Comment: also, your mapDispatchToProps in ControlPopover looks odd. I believe you need to modify it to return a function like mapStateToProps. This could be throwing an error causing the state update to not propagate.

Comment: mapStateToProps was being called but I was binding to the wrong object property

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is your `mapDispatchToProp` functions are not formatted properly.

You need to return an object that has methods. Those methods are what will be given to your connected component as props.

Example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return {
        doSomething: ( arguments ) => {
            // here you can dispatch and use your arguments
        } 
    };
}
```

`doSomething` is the prop that would be provided to the connected component.

All of your mapDispatchToProps functions are formatted improperly.

**SIDE NOTE / OPINION - TLDR**:

In the future if you have a lot of code to post, I believe it would be easier to digest if the pieces were linked together.

I.E.

```
// App.js
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Body />
        <Footer />
    </div>
);
```

The components appear in the order: header -> body -> footer. Provide the code for them in that order, with their actions, reducer, presentational, and container information in one block.

Header

```
// header.presentational.js ...

// header.container.js ... ( or where you mapStateToProps and connect )

// header.actions.js ...

// header.reducer.js ...
```

Body ...

Footer ...

I don't know if the code is different on your end, but your `mapStateToDispatch` function is still improperly formatted.

Change this...

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleEditInvoice: invoice => {
    dispatch(showInvoiceEditPopover(invoice))
  }
})
```

To this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  return {
    handleEditInvoice: invoice => {
      dispatch(showInvoiceEditPopover(invoice))
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the feedback on the formatting. the 
```const mapDispatchToProps = {
  handleCancel: closePopoverWithoutSave
}```

appears to be badly formatted, yes. This wouldn't get called until after the popover were opened though. In any case fixing this function does not fix the problem. The Popover component is still not getting rendered.

Comment: Would you post the code to your `createModifiers` please.

Comment: Posted createModifiers above.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in containers/ControlPopover.js and the `mapStateToProps` function. The `isActive` property needs to be assigned to `state.popover.isActive`